# JPA based Criteria query for finding entity by field name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

I dont know if its me who finds criteria queries with JPA difficult.
What to do next in order to get Tag(s) with name = :tagNam

```
    Tag getTagByName(String tagName){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tag> cq = cb.createQuery(Tag.class);
        Root<Tag> root = cq.from(Tag.class);
        **//what to do next in order to get Tag(s) with name = :tagNam**
    }
```

`Tag` is an entity with field `name`

I have viewed:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/
3. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery

But was unable to grasp concepts. Is there an easy step by step or comprehensive tutorial too?

I am also frustrated as I was required (according to tutorials) to do use `Tag_` which does not resolves of course.

Comment: you configured the annotation processor? check out http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e302

Comment: There are ample tutorials on the web, for example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html   Just do what it does, it creates the metamodel (the _ classes) and then is simple

Comment: hm. will check meta models now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tag> cq = cb.createQuery(Tag.class);
Root<Tag> tag = cq.from(Tag.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(tag.get(Tag_.name), tagName));
```

This is adapted from oracle documentation(your first link).

Comment: on your last line, `tag` does NOT have a `.get()` method

Comment: That's not get() method of Tag class. It's a method of the Root<> Interface, inherited from Path interface. So it should be there...

Comment: It can't resolve `Tag_`
I think it has something to do with `meta models` (which I don't want to use)

Comment: Then why don't use JPQL? You can get it work with something like: "from Tag t where t.name := tagName"...

Comment: Aurasphere: valid suggestion but I am moving away from JPQL. I used it before. Both methods have their own pros and cons. This stack question is about criteria only

Comment: Ok but you know that it's either you go Criteria AND Metamodel or you go JPQL, right? So if you don't want to use JPQL you will need to use MetaModel to filter your results... That said, I still think that this tutorial you posted is pretty simple... http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html

Comment: How to use metamodels then?  so `Tag_.name` would resolve?

Comment: actually its not resolving unless (I GUESS) I implement metamodel. I am reading http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html

Comment: Yeah I meant that it will work if you follow the tutorial. Anyway I'm glad I could help you.